# Binding OpenGL texture to OpenCL buffer

Tags: opengl, interop, opencl

I am working on some project with require of some rendering using OpenGL, and then passing output texture for OpenCL post-processing. The problem is that our kernels work with buffers, not images, and the final output also should be buffer, so changing kernels for work with image2d instead of buffers is not an option.

Of course, mapping OpenGL buffer/texture to the same type on OpenCL is an easy task, but it seems that there are no direct way to map OpenGL output (both texture or renderbuffer objects) to OpenCL buffer without additional steps/memory allocation as copying GL texture data to PBO or CL image to buffer etc. Ability to bind GL buffer objects as framebuffer output would be nice, but I haven't found anything like this so far. I thought about GL_TEXTURE_BUFFER as rendering target, but OpenGL prohibits to use it with framebuffer.

So, the question is - is there any way to directly render with OpenGL into vertex buffer object, and if no - what is the most efficient (time/memory) way to convert OpenGL texture into OpenCL buffer?

Comment: There are lots of examples around, here's one: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/OpenCL_Procedural_Geometric_Displacement_Example/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: @lll You misunderstood me a bit. I know about binding VBO to OpenCL buffer, but the problem is in binding texture to buffer. Binding  GL texture to CL image - is OK. Binding GL buffer to CL buffer - is OK. But the question is about texture-to-buffer.

Comment: ...`clCreateFromGLBuffer` or `clCreateFromGLTexture2D` wouldn't work?

Comment: I need to bind data from existing `GL_TEXTURE_2D` into cl buffer. I can do it by simple pipeline like `clCreateFromGLTexture2D` -> `clEnqueueCopyImageToBuffer` , or with creating PBO and binding CL buffer to it, but i'm trying to avoid this copying and spare memory allocation.

Comment: Ah, okay... I think that's more or less the standard way of updating a GL texture from CL, and overhead is fairly minimal. The only other suggestion from my end is possibly using texture sharing or buffer sharing; minimal examples here: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/56b65c82cfcd2e92117a3ea599b87c25